# How do I remove comma and brackets

Tags: python, python-2.7, cx-oracle

This is my output from using the Cx_Oracle lib

```
('DATABASE2',)
(000000000000,)
(000000000000,)
('DATABASE1',)
(000000000000,)
(000000000000,)
('DATABASE3',)
```

How do i remove the '' , and (). It is a string.

Comment: `re.sub(r'\W', '', line)`

Comment: this works - what does the '\W' do   thanks!

Comment: `\W` matches any non-word character ie, any char other than `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re 
ans_con=(str(d))
print re.sub(r'\W', '', ans_con)
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 2):

Its just a value inside a tuple! if you want the direct value just access it as you would normally do with a list or tuple. ie `('DATABASE3',)[0]`

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
a = ('DATABASE2',)
print a[0]
```

Comment: I get int object not subscriptiable when I try doing that.

Answer (score 0):

suppose I have:

```
a = ('DATABASE2',)
```

Check type:

```
type(a)
```

will give you `<type 'tuple'>`

Thus you can print it as array:

```
print a[0]
```

Or if you want to capture output as string, simply use:

```
print str(a[0])
```

I don't think we need to apply any complex regex logics here.